# How to enable software collection software

Tags: chef-infra, chef-recipe

I'm new to Chef and I'm trying to write a Chef recipe that will install php 5.6 from software collection.

The installation steps are the following:

```
// Step:1
sudo yum install centos-release-scl //id Centos
sudo yum-config-manager --enable rhel-server-rhscl-7-rpms //if RHEL
// Step:2
sudo yum install rh-php56
// Step: 3
scl enable rh-php56 bash
```

What I did so far:

```
case node['platform']
when 'centos'
  yum_package 'centos-release-scl'
when 'rhel'
  bash 'enable RHSCL' do
    code 'sudo yum-config-manager --enable rhel-server-rhscl-7-rpms'
  end
end

package 'rh-php56'

execute 'software-collection' do
  command 'scl enable rh-php56 bash'
end
```

I don't know why the last part of enable the `rh-php56` is not working.
I've tried with bash resource but still no result.

Cheers.

Answer (score 1):

The issue that `scl enable` only enables the collection for the specific command you give there (`bash` in your example). It isn't a global setting. You'll have to preface every PHP command with `scl enable`. I don't have a cookbook for PHP, but check out how poise-ruby and poise-python handle SCLs for an example of handling this more globally within Chef.